# How to remove artifacts from texture on a sphere?

Tags: javascript, webgl

I created a sphere and added a texture to it using code mainly from lesson 11 of "Learning WebGL" (http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?p=1253).

It all works fine, but when i animate a rotation of the sphere around its x- or y-axis, there partially appear thin lines where the latitude- and longitude-bands are - like they'd shine through the texture, what - of cause - should not be the case.

It's not the best shot, but you can see some of these thin lines around the equator of the sphere on the picture here:

http://fs1.directupload.net/images/150313/n62liv5i.jpg

There is no difference whether i add lighting to the scene or not, and the effect appears in Firefox as well as in Internet Explorer.

I'm relatively new to WebGL / graphic programming and have no idea how to prevent this unwelcome effect!

The code for the sphere-creation and the texture-handling is pretty much the same as provided on the website linked above, so, to handle the loaded texture, i use the following function

```
function handleLoadedTexture (texture) {
  gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.RGBA,
                gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture.image);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,
                   gl.LINEAR);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
                   gl.LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
  gl.generateMipmap(gl.TEXTURE_2D);
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, null);
}
```

and the sphere is created by this one:

```
function sphere (rad) {
  var latitudeBands = 50,
      longitudeBands = 50;
  var radius = rad;
  var vertexPositionData = [ ],
      normalData = [ ],
      textureCoordData = [ ];
  var latNum,
      longNum;
  for (latNum = 0; latNum <= latitudeBands; latNum++) {
    var theta = latNum * Math.PI / latitudeBands;
    var sinTheta = Math.sin(theta),
        cosTheta = Math.cos(theta);
    for (longNum = 0; longNum <= longitudeBands; longNum++) {
      var phi = longNum * 2 * Math.PI / longitudeBands;
      var sinPhi = Math.sin(phi),
          cosPhi = Math.cos(phi);
      var x = cosPhi * sinTheta,
          y = cosTheta;
          z = sinPhi * sinTheta;
      var u = 1 - (longNum / longitudeBands),
          v = 1 - (latNum / latitudeBands);
      normalData.push(x);
      normalData.push(y);
      normalData.push(z);
      textureCoordData.push(u);
      textureCoordData.push(v);
      vertexPositionData.push(radius * x);
      vertexPositionData.push(radius * y);
      vertexPositionData.push(radius * z);
    }
  }
  var indexData = [ ];
  for (latNum = 0; latNum < latitudeBands; latNum++) {
    for (longNum = 0; longNum < longitudeBands; longNum++) {
      var first = (latNum * (longitudeBands + 1)) + longNum;
      var second = first + longitudeBands + 1;
      indexData.push(first);
      indexData.push(second);
      indexData.push(first + 1);
      indexData.push(second);
      indexData.push(second + 1);
      indexData.push(first + 1);
    }
  }
  this.normalData = normalData;
  this.textureCoordData = textureCoordData;
  this.vertexPositionData = vertexPositionData;
  this.indexData = indexData;
}
```

I think these should be the relevant parts of the code, but if you think they're not, i can add more of it on demand.

I'd be thankful for any hint helping me to solve the problem!

PS: Please excuse my bad english! - It's not my first language.

Comment: An image of the problem would be helpful.

Comment: when I execute the demo and see its moon texture it too has such boarder lines visible if you roll to view the backside of the moon ... maybe the lines are just part of the texture

Comment: Well, I don't think so. As you can see on the screenshot linked in my post, these lines also appear when I don't use the moon-texture from the linked page. In fact, I tried a couple of diffrent textures on the model and the effect remained the same. Therefore I think the problem has to be located somewhere in the function by which the model of the sphere is created. - I just can't put the finger on it!

Comment: Just for the record i do not see any line artifacts like yours on the sample(Chrome Stable - Linux). Besides that you may want to build a your sphere from a [tessellated icosahedron](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/561093/how-to-generate-a-subdivided-icosahedron)

Comment: Thanks for the input! I was looking for alternative ways to design the sphere, but could't find any useful links until now! I see, I will have to translate the code from your link to javascript, but it really looks promising!

Comment: Ok. It _looked_ promising, but to be honest, I'm nowhere near of being skilled enough to get this one working. I searched for some tutorials or javascript examples elsewhere, but couldn't find anything useful, so I think I'll have to stick with what I got... Nevertheless thanks for the idea!